# How to localize a Rails plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, internationalization

I'd like to translate the OpenIdAuthentication plugin into another language but I'd like not to change the plugin directly.

Here's the basic structure of the messages I want to translate:

```
module OpenIdAuthentication

  class Result
    ERROR_MESSAGES = {
      :missing      => "Sorry, the OpenID server couldn't be found",
      :invalid      => "Sorry, but this does not appear to be a valid OpenID",
      :canceled     => "OpenID verification was canceled",
      :failed       => "OpenID verification failed",
      :setup_needed => "OpenID verification needs setup"
    } 
  end

end
```

It is something possible to translate them without changing the plugin directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply overwrite `OpenIdAuthentication::Result::ERROR_MESSAGES` by redefining it at any time after the plugin loads.

You may do so through a different plugin (that loads after `OpenIdAuthentication`), or from a file required after the plugin loads (e.g. `require lib/open_id_authentication_suppl.rb` in `environment.rb`):

The code will essentially be a copy-paste job, as follows:

```
module OpenIdAuthentication

  class Result
    ERROR_MESSAGES = {
      :missing      => "<message in foreign language>",
      :invalid      => "<message in foreign language>",
      :canceled     => "<message in foreign language>",
      :failed       => "<message in foreign language>",
      :setup_needed => "<message in foreign language>"
    } 
  end
```

To integrate this with [I18N-rails](http://rails-i18n.org/wiki/pages/i18n-rails-guide) (built into Rails 2.2.2, available as a gem/plugin in previous versions), do:

```
  class I18NResultMessages
    def [](key)
      I18n.t(key, :scope => 'openidauthentication.errors.messages')
    end
  end

  class Result
    ERROR_MESSAGES = I18NResultMessages.new
  end
```

Then define and load your I18n yml file for `openidauthentication.errors.messages`'s various locales on Rails startup, and don't forget to set your `I18n.locale` every time you start processing a controller action based on the logged-in user's locale.

Comment: Thank you! This code does work! So I think there's no way to use the yml file in locales directly because the plugin isn't ready for i18n. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Copy that code into a file in `/lib`, then require it in `environment.rb`. It really is that easy.