# How easily convert boolean to yes/no using Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, formatting, boolean

I have an easy problem - I need to convert boolean (contract_pledge) to yes/no format in Russian language (Да/Нет). I thought I could easily find an answer because if you want to display checkboxes in show page in seem to be natural.
I found these two posts:

- [Rails (or Ruby): Yes/No instead of True/False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664181/rails-or-ruby-yes-no-instead-of-true-false)
- [How to localize a Rails plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622250/how-to-localize-a-rails-plugin)

I tried to combine them but I failed. Now I have Yes/No only in English.
Thats what I have in my view /views/lots/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@lot.tender,@lot]) do |f| %>
<table>
...
<tr>
<td class="right"><b><%= f.label :contract_pledge %></b></td>
<td><%=t @lot.contract_pledge.yesno %></td>
</tr>
...
</table>
<% end %>
```

That's the file /config/initializers/boolean_path.rb I created:

```
class FalseClass
  def yesno
    "No"
  end
end

class TrueClass
  def yesno
    "Yes"
   end
end
```

That's my /config/locales/ru.yml

```
ru:
    yesno:
      Yes: "Да"
      No: "Нет"
```

Of course I can solve the problem inserting Russian language in Lot view, but I want to do it in rails way. I will appreciate any help, and I think that this question will be useful for other rails young programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return "Yes" or "No", so you have to translate these keys:

```
<td><%= t @lot.contract_pledge.yesno %></td>
```

You may also find useful http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale from section 2.3 to 2.6

Comment: I tried _t_ funclion just the way you wrote but it still return english Yes. Default locale is already set. It works OK with ActiveRecord localization

Comment: do you mean I18n.locale is :ru?

Comment: in my application.rb file I have 'config.i18n.default_locale = :ru'